# Cabin condensed not working as expected with TeXLive 2019?

Tags: fonts, texlive, texlive-2019

I like to use the excellent Cabin Condensed font by Pablo Impallari. I switch to this font using the handy `\cabincondensed` command defined by the [cabin](https://ctan.org/pkg/cabin) package. However, after I updated to TeXLive 2019 this command is not working as expected. To discard issues with my local installation, I used Overleaf to test this minimum example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cabin}
\begin{document}
\cabincondensed Hello world
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get this:

[image]

However, if I switch the compiler to TeXLive 2018 (thanks Overleaf for that functionality) I get the expected font:

[image]

My question is, is the issue with the `cabin` package? With TeXLive 2019? And most importantly, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You wrote, "... after I updated to TeXLive 2019 …" TeXLive2020 has been the most to date TeXLive distribution for more than half a year. Any chance you could update to TeXLive2020 and check if the font issue persists?

Comment: @Mico I try to keep the same version as in Overleaf (which is 2019), so through Dropbox integration I can seamlessly write and compile either through a local, offline installation, or online through Overleaf.

Comment: Well this is awkward, it seems that Overleaf has added TeXLive2020 today! Unfortunately the error still appears in TeXLive2020 exactly as in 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command has changed (probably to adjust to some changes in LaTeX regarding font series): it now only switches the series, and not the font family. This means that you have to select the family too e.g. with `\cabin` or `\sffamily` (I'm not sure if this was intended).

Beside this, the command has a bug, it contains spurious spaces:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cabin}
\begin{document}
H\cabin\cabincondensed ello world
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did notice this but since it generated spurious spaces I thought this was not the intended use. Any idea on how to consistently get rid of the space? In any case I will contact the package maintainer to report the bug.